# If I do sets of 15-25 reps, how many sets should I am for per week?

Tags: bodybuilding

During lockdown, I am doing workouts at home with two dumbells. I can't add any more weight, so I am doing sets in the 15-25 rep range.

How many sets should I aim for per week for large (leg, chest, back) and small (arms) muscles per week?

The goal is muscle growth.

Also, how much time to rest between sets? Due to the low weight, I am trying to add more tension by going to failure often and resting little between sets. Good idea or not?

Comment: The specific number of reps matters a lot less than the number of sets that are brought within a reasonable proximity of failure. But the number of sets depends on both the specific muscle group as well as the variability of the individual. This article goes in depth on volume recommendations and more. https://renaissanceperiodization.com/hypertrophy-training-guide-central-hub/

Answer (score -1):

It seems the daily peak is around 7 sets per muscle building but it seems people can tollerate way more than that before running into overtraing.

Also the highest weekly number of sets ever clinically tested was 45 sets per muscle group,it seems it held the most muscle growth.

You should manage by yourself the amount of sets you want to do, because everyone  has a different recovery. While  it seem fun and cool and extreme to do 20 sets of one exercise in a day...it won't be good if you can't recover from that.

Train as much as you can recover. But if you wanna be safe and not risk wrecking yourself for one entire week or more for nothing, then just stick to 7 sets per day or less. [Source](https://medium.com/@SandCResearch/what-is-the-maximum-number-of-stimulating-reps-that-we-can-do-in-a-workout-for-a-muscle-group-9379d91bf2c)

Answer (score -1):

Typically, increasing the number of reps/sets compared to previous sessions, and lowering the amount of rest time should stimulate muscle growth. So a gradual increase week by week should provide results. See link: https://www.stack.com/a/unconventional-build-muscle/

Larger muscle growth in an area usually means you need to work out that area with an increasingly more significant amount of weight. Not always, but generally that is the case.

If you cannot add additional weight, try doing different exercises in that same general area, then just lifting weights, such as resistance training, bodyweight exercises, or suspension training. For example, if you want your arms to get bigger and only have dumbells, try doing pushups with different arm spacing, or at different angles, or work at trying to do a handstand. Once you're able to do a handstand after much practice, your arms will have to support most of your bodyweight. This would potentially be more weight than you're used to if you just have dumbells.

https://www.thegoodbody.com/how-to-build-muscle-without-lifting-weights/